# How to debug a GnuCOBOL program using cobcdd in Oracle Linux?

Tags: debugging, gdb, gnucobol

I'm trying to use cobcd (cobolworkx - Version 4.28.4) to debug a program. The command is returning the following error on Oracle Linux (Oracle Linux Server release 8.7, GnuCOBOL 3.1.2 and gcc 8.5.0):

```
cobcd -x program.cob
program.s: Assembler messages:
program.s:13870: Error: leb128 operand is an undefined symbol: .LVU139
program.s:13871: Error: leb128 operand is an undefined symbol: .LVU139
```

Do you have any solution?

Comment: missing information - version of:

Oracle Linux, GnuCOBOL, cbl-gdb package from COBOLworx, C compiler